# How to Backup Microsft DNS Server Log Before Hitting Maximum Size?

Tags: domain-name-system, backup, windows-server-2012-r2

[image]

I'm not seeing any way to send these DNS Logs to a remote server for cold storage. Is there a built-in way to make sure Windows sends log entries to another server (or file!) before it hits Maximum Size and rotates the logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following cmdlet to ensure that the log file rolls over, at that point, you can have the data copied over to another location.

```
Set-DnsServerDiagnostics -EnableLogFileRollover $True
```

If enabling this setting, you'll want to ensure that you either

1. Monitor drive space carefully, as this can fill up the system drive, or
2. Run a scheduled task that monitors the path for new files and copies / deletes when created, or
3. Change the log file path to an alternate location, so as to not affect the system drive: `Set-DnsServerDiagnostics -LogFilePath 'D:\Path\To\logs'`

---

Further cmdlet reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsserver/set-dnsserverdiagnostics